# memory leak occurs in hibernate while updating bean

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, memory-leaks, hibernate-mapping

I am getting error **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** while i am updating profile  detail of student..

error stack:

```
Hibernate: select studentbea0_.studentID as studentID7_42_, studentbea0_.studentFullName as studentF2_7_42_, studentbea0_.studentAddress as studentA3_7_42_, studentbea0_.studentCity as studentC4_7_42_, studentbea0_.studentState as studentS5_7_42_, studentbea0_.studentCountry as studentC6_7_42_, studentbea0_.className as className7_42_, studentbea0_.birthDate as birthDate7_42_, studentbea0_.studentContactNo as studentC9_7_42_, studentbea0_.studentPassword as student10_7_42_, studentbea0_.studentFacebookPage as student11_7_42_, studentbea0_.studentEmailId as student12_7_42_, studentbea0_.outsideuser as outside13_7_42_, studentbea0_.studentPhoto as student14_7_42_, studentbea0_.studentResume as student15_7_42_, studentbea0_.schooolName10 as schoool16_7_42_, studentbea0_.board10 as board17_7_42_, studentbea0_.marks10 as marks18_7_42_, studentbea0_.schooolName12 as schoool19_7_42_, studentbea0_.board12 as board20_7_42_, studentbea0_.marks12 as marks21_7_42_, studentbea0_.collegeNameUG as college22_7_42_, studentbea0_.boardUG as boardUG7_42_, studentbea0_.marksUG as marksUG7_42_, studentbea0_.collegeNamePG as college25_7_42_, studentbea0_.boardPG as boardPG7_42_, studentbea0_.marksPG as marksPG7_42_, studentbea0_.technologyknown as technol28_7_42_, studentbea0_.resume as resume7_42_, studentbea0_.date_time as date30_7_42_, studentbea0_.collegeID as collegeID7_42_, studentbea0_.courseID as courseID7_42_, collegebea1_.collegeid as collegeid0_0_, collegebea1_.collegeEmailID as collegeE2_0_0_, collegebea1_.collegename as collegen3_0_0_, collegebea1_.collegeaddress as collegea4_0_0_, collegebea1_.collegecity as collegec5_0_0_, collegebea1_.collegewebsite as collegew6_0_0_, collegebea1_.collegedescription as colleged7_0_0_, collegebea1_.collegecontactno as collegec8_0_0_, collegebea1_.collegepassword as collegep9_0_0_, collegebea1_.collegefacebookPage as college10_0_0_, collegebea1_.collegeState as college11_0_0_, collegebea1_.collegeCountry as college12_0_0_, collegebea1_.date_time as date13_0_0_, collegebea1_.pincode as pincode0_0_, college_co2_.collegeID as collegeID0_44_, college_co2_.college_course_ID as college1_44_, college_co2_.college_course_ID as college1_1_1_, college_co2_.date_time as date2_1_1_, college_co2_.courseID as courseID1_1_, college_co2_.collegeID as collegeID1_1_, testbean3_.collegeID as collegeID0_45_, testbean3_.testID as testID45_, testbean3_.testID as testID9_2_, testbean3_.testfile as testfile9_2_, testbean3_.questionSheet as question3_9_2_, testbean3_.teststatus as teststatus9_2_, testbean3_.totalmMark as totalmMark9_2_, testbean3_.time as time9_2_, testbean3_.type as type9_2_, testbean3_.testName as testName9_2_, testbean3_.examcode as examcode9_2_, testbean3_.description as descrip10_9_2_, testbean3_.students as students9_2_, testbean3_.date_time as date12_9_2_, testbean3_.collegeID as collegeID9_2_, testbean3_.subjectID as subjectID9_2_, testbean3_.facultyID as facultyID9_2_, collegeact4_.collegeID as collegeID0_46_, collegeact4_.sessionID as sessionID46_, collegeact4_.sessionID as sessionID23_3_, collegeact4_.loginTime as loginTime23_3_, collegeact4_.logoutTime as logoutTime23_3_, collegeact4_.ipAddress as ipAddress23_3_, collegeact4_.collegeID as collegeID23_3_, assignment5_.collegeID as collegeID0_47_, assignment5_.assignmentID as assignme1_47_, assignment5_.assignmentID as assignme1_17_4_, assignment5_.assignmentfile as assignme2_17_4_, assignment5_.assignmentstatus as assignme3_17_4_, assignment5_.assignmentName as assignme4_17_4_, assignment5_.description as descript5_17_4_, assignment5_.date_time as date6_17_4_, assignment5_.collegeID as collegeID17_4_, assignment5_.subjectID as subjectID17_4_, assignment5_.facultyID as facultyID17_4_, coursebean6_.courseid as courseid2_5_, coursebean6_.courseName as courseName2_5_, coursebean6_.noofsemester as noofseme3_2_5_, coursebean6_.date_time as date4_2_5_, subjectbea7_.courseID as courseID2_48_, subjectbea7_.subjectid as subjectid48_, subjectbea7_.subjectid as subjectid8_6_, subjectbea7_.subjectName as subjectN2_8_6_, subjectbea7_.semester as semester8_6_, subjectbea7_.practical as practical8_6_, subjectbea7_.date_time as date5_8_6_, subjectbea7_.courseID as courseID8_6_, faculty_su8_.courseID as courseID2_49_, faculty_su8_.faculty_subject_ID as faculty1_49_, faculty_su8_.faculty_subject_ID as faculty1_3_7_, faculty_su8_.date_time as date2_3_7_, faculty_su8_.courseID as courseID3_7_, faculty_su8_.subjectID as subjectID3_7_, faculty_su8_.facultyID as facultyID3_7_, college_co9_.courseID as courseID2_50_, college_co9_.college_course_ID as college1_50_, college_co9_.college_course_ID as college1_1_8_, college_co9_.date_time as date2_1_8_, college_co9_.courseID as courseID1_8_, college_co9_.collegeID as collegeID1_8_, jobcourseb10_.courseID as courseID2_51_, jobcourseb10_.jobcourseid as jobcours1_51_, jobcourseb10_.jobcourseid as jobcours1_26_9_, jobcourseb10_.courseID as courseID26_9_, jobcourseb10_.jobID as jobID26_9_, studentact11_.studentID as studentID7_52_, studentact11_.sessionID as sessionID52_, studentact11_.sessionID as sessionID22_10_, studentact11_.loginTime as loginTime22_10_, studentact11_.logoutTime as logoutTime22_10_, studentact11_.ipAddress as ipAddress22_10_, studentact11_.studentID as studentID22_10_, jobviewbea12_.studentID as studentID7_53_, jobviewbea12_.jobviewid as jobviewid53_, jobviewbea12_.jobviewid as jobviewid27_11_, jobviewbea12_.studentID as studentID27_11_, jobviewbea12_.jobID as jobID27_11_, jobbean13_.jobid as jobid20_12_, jobbean13_.jobtitle as jobtitle20_12_, jobbean13_.companyname as companyn3_20_12_, jobbean13_.description as descript4_20_12_, jobbean13_.experience as experience20_12_, jobbean13_.technologies as technolo6_20_12_, jobbean13_.designation as designat7_20_12_, jobbean13_.salary as salary20_12_, jobbean13_.bonus as bonus20_12_, jobbean13_.cities as cities20_12_, jobbean13_.vacancies as vacancies20_12_, jobbean13_.location as location20_12_, jobbean13_.jobtype as jobtype20_12_, jobbean13_.date_time as date14_20_12_, jobbean13_.recruiterID as recruit15_20_12_, jobbean13_.categoryTypeID as categor16_20_12_, jobbean13_.categoryID as categoryID20_12_, applyjobbe14_.studentID as studentID7_54_, applyjobbe14_.applyjobid as applyjobid54_, applyjobbe14_.applyjobid as applyjobid21_13_, applyjobbe14_.date_time as date2_21_13_, applyjobbe14_.studentID as studentID21_13_, applyjobbe14_.jobID as jobID21_13_, jobbean15_.jobid as jobid20_14_, jobbean15_.jobtitle as jobtitle20_14_, jobbean15_.companyname as companyn3_20_14_, jobbean15_.description as descript4_20_14_, jobbean15_.experience as experience20_14_, jobbean15_.technologies as technolo6_20_14_, jobbean15_.designation as designat7_20_14_, jobbean15_.salary as salary20_14_, jobbean15_.bonus as bonus20_14_, jobbean15_.cities as cities20_14_, jobbean15_.vacancies as vacancies20_14_, jobbean15_.location as location20_14_, jobbean15_.jobtype as jobtype20_14_, jobbean15_.date_time as date14_20_14_, jobbean15_.recruiterID as recruit15_20_14_, jobbean15_.categoryTypeID as categor16_20_14_, jobbean15_.categoryID as categoryID20_14_, likevideob16_.studentID as studentID7_55_, likevideob16_.likevideoid as likevide1_55_, likevideob16_.likevideoid as likevide1_31_15_, likevideob16_.date_time as date2_31_15_, likevideob16_.studentID as studentID31_15_, likevideob16_.videoID as videoID31_15_, videobean17_.videoid as videoid15_16_, videobean17_.videoname as videoname15_16_, videobean17_.description as descript3_15_16_, videobean17_.videopath as videopath15_16_, videobean17_.status as status15_16_, videobean17_.usertype as usertype15_16_, videobean17_.author as author15_16_, videobean17_.tag as tag15_16_, videobean17_.likedby as likedby15_16_, videobean17_.date_time as date10_15_16_, videobean17_.categoryID as categoryID15_16_, commentvid18_.studentID as studentID7_56_, commentvid18_.commentvideoid as commentv1_56_, commentvid18_.commentvideoid as commentv1_32_17_, commentvid18_.date_time as date2_32_17_, commentvid18_.comment as comment32_17_, commentvid18_.studentID as studentID32_17_, commentvid18_.videoID as videoID32_17_, videobean19_.videoid as videoid15_18_, videobean19_.videoname as videoname15_18_, videobean19_.description as descript3_15_18_, videobean19_.videopath as videopath15_18_, videobean19_.status as status15_18_, videobean19_.usertype as usertype15_18_, videobean19_.author as author15_18_, videobean19_.tag as tag15_18_, videobean19_.likedby as likedby15_18_, videobean19_.date_time as date10_15_18_, videobean19_.categoryID as categoryID15_18_, likequoteb20_.studentID as studentID7_57_, likequoteb20_.likequoteid as likequot1_57_, likequoteb20_.likequoteid as likequot1_44_19_, likequoteb20_.date_time as date2_44_19_, likequoteb20_.studentID as studentID44_19_, likequoteb20_.quoteid as quoteid44_19_, quotebean21_.quoteid as quoteid16_20_, quotebean21_.quotename as quotename16_20_, quotebean21_.description as descript3_16_20_, quotebean21_.quotepath as quotepath16_20_, quotebean21_.status as status16_20_, quotebean21_.usertype as usertype16_20_, quotebean21_.author as author16_20_, quotebean21_.date_time as date8_16_20_, quotebean21_.categoryID as categoryID16_20_, commentquo22_.studentID as studentID7_58_, commentquo22_.commentquoteid as commentq1_58_, commentquo22_.commentquoteid as commentq1_43_21_, commentquo22_.date_time as date2_43_21_, commentquo22_.comment as comment43_21_, commentquo22_.studentID as studentID43_21_, commentquo22_.quoteid as quoteid43_21_, quotebean23_.quoteid as quoteid16_22_, quotebean23_.quotename as quotename16_22_, quotebean23_.description as descript3_16_22_, quotebean23_.quotepath as quotepath16_22_, quotebean23_.status as status16_22_, quotebean23_.usertype as usertype16_22_, quotebean23_.author as author16_22_, quotebean23_.date_time as date8_16_22_, quotebean23_.categoryID as categoryID16_22_, likearticl24_.studentID as studentID7_59_, likearticl24_.likearticlesid as likearti1_59_, likearticl24_.likearticlesid as likearti1_38_23_, likearticl24_.date_time as date2_38_23_, likearticl24_.studentID as studentID38_23_, likearticl24_.articlesid as articlesid38_23_, articlesbe25_.articlesid as articlesid14_24_, articlesbe25_.articlesname as articles2_14_24_, articlesbe25_.description as descript3_14_24_, articlesbe25_.articlespath as articles4_14_24_, articlesbe25_.status as status14_24_, articlesbe25_.usertype as usertype14_24_, articlesbe25_.author as author14_24_, articlesbe25_.date_time as date8_14_24_, articlesbe25_.likedby as likedby14_24_, articlesbe25_.categoryID as categoryID14_24_, commentart26_.studentID as studentID7_60_, commentart26_.commentarticlesid as commenta1_60_, commentart26_.commentarticlesid as commenta1_37_25_, commentart26_.date_time as date2_37_25_, commentart26_.comment as comment37_25_, commentart26_.studentID as studentID37_25_, commentart26_.articlesID as articlesID37_25_, articlesbe27_.articlesid as articlesid14_26_, articlesbe27_.articlesname as articles2_14_26_, articlesbe27_.description as descript3_14_26_, articlesbe27_.articlespath as articles4_14_26_, articlesbe27_.status as status14_26_, articlesbe27_.usertype as usertype14_26_, articlesbe27_.author as author14_26_, articlesbe27_.date_time as date8_14_26_, articlesbe27_.likedby as likedby14_26_, articlesbe27_.categoryID as categoryID14_26_, likelifecl28_.studentID as studentID7_61_, likelifecl28_.likelifeclubvideoid as likelife1_61_, likelifecl28_.likelifeclubvideoid as likelife1_29_27_, likelifecl28_.date_time as date2_29_27_, likelifecl28_.studentID as studentID29_27_, likelifecl28_.videoid as videoid29_27_, lifeclubvi29_.videoid as videoid28_28_, lifeclubvi29_.videoname as videoname28_28_, lifeclubvi29_.description as descript3_28_28_, lifeclubvi29_.videopath as videopath28_28_, lifeclubvi29_.status as status28_28_, lifeclubvi29_.usertype as usertype28_28_, lifeclubvi29_.author as author28_28_, lifeclubvi29_.tag as tag28_28_, lifeclubvi29_.likedby as likedby28_28_, lifeclubvi29_.date_time as date10_28_28_, lifeclubvi29_.categoryID as categoryID28_28_, commentlif30_.studentID as studentID7_62_, commentlif30_.commentlifeclubvideoid as commentl1_62_, commentlif30_.commentlifeclubvideoid as commentl1_30_29_, commentlif30_.date_time as date2_30_29_, commentlif30_.comment as comment30_29_, commentlif30_.studentID as studentID30_29_, commentlif30_.videoid as videoid30_29_, lifeclubvi31_.videoid as videoid28_30_, lifeclubvi31_.videoname as videoname28_30_, lifeclubvi31_.description as descript3_28_30_, lifeclubvi31_.videopath as videopath28_30_, lifeclubvi31_.status as status28_30_, lifeclubvi31_.usertype as usertype28_30_, lifeclubvi31_.author as author28_30_, lifeclubvi31_.tag as tag28_30_, lifeclubvi31_.likedby as likedby28_30_, lifeclubvi31_.date_time as date10_28_30_, lifeclubvi31_.categoryID as categoryID28_30_, likeebookb32_.studentID as studentID7_63_, likeebookb32_.likeebookid as likeeboo1_63_, likeebookb32_.likeebookid as likeeboo1_33_31_, likeebookb32_.date_time as date2_33_31_, likeebookb32_.studentID as studentID33_31_, likeebookb32_.ebookID as ebookID33_31_, ebookbean33_.ebookid as ebookid13_32_, ebookbean33_.ebookname as ebookname13_32_, ebookbean33_.description as descript3_13_32_, ebookbean33_.ebookpath as ebookpath13_32_, ebookbean33_.status as status13_32_, ebookbean33_.usertype as usertype13_32_, ebookbean33_.author as author13_32_, ebookbean33_.likedby as likedby13_32_, ebookbean33_.date_time as date9_13_32_, ebookbean33_.categoryID as categoryID13_32_, commentebo34_.studentID as studentID7_64_, commentebo34_.commentebookid as commente1_64_, commentebo34_.commentebookid as commente1_34_33_, commentebo34_.date_time as date2_34_33_, commentebo34_.comment as comment34_33_, commentebo34_.studentID as studentID34_33_, commentebo34_.ebookID as ebookID34_33_, ebookbean35_.ebookid as ebookid13_34_, ebookbean35_.ebookname as ebookname13_34_, ebookbean35_.description as descript3_13_34_, ebookbean35_.ebookpath as ebookpath13_34_, ebookbean35_.status as status13_34_, ebookbean35_.usertype as usertype13_34_, ebookbean35_.author as author13_34_, ebookbean35_.likedby as likedby13_34_, ebookbean35_.date_time as date9_13_34_, ebookbean35_.categoryID as categoryID13_34_, submitassi36_.studentID as studentID7_65_, submitassi36_.submitassignmentid as submitas1_65_, submitassi36_.submitassignmentid as submitas1_18_35_, submitassi36_.date_time as date2_18_35_, submitassi36_.message as message18_35_, submitassi36_.assignmentfile as assignme4_18_35_, submitassi36_.studentID as studentID18_35_, submitassi36_.assignmentID as assignme6_18_35_, assignment37_.assignmentID as assignme1_17_36_, assignment37_.assignmentfile as assignme2_17_36_, assignment37_.assignmentstatus as assignme3_17_36_, assignment37_.assignmentName as assignme4_17_36_, assignment37_.description as descript5_17_36_, assignment37_.date_time as date6_17_36_, assignment37_.collegeID as collegeID17_36_, assignment37_.subjectID as subjectID17_36_, assignment37_.facultyID as facultyID17_36_, helpinghan38_.studentID as studentID7_66_, helpinghan38_.helpinghandID as helpingh1_66_, helpinghan38_.helpinghandID as helpingh1_46_37_, helpinghan38_.date_time as date2_46_37_, helpinghan38_.lastpostby as lastpostby46_37_, helpinghan38_.title as title46_37_, helpinghan38_.post as post46_37_, helpinghan38_.category as category46_37_, helpinghan38_.studentID as studentID46_37_, viewhelpin39_.helpinghandID as helpingh4_46_67_, viewhelpin39_.viewhelpinghandpostID as viewhelp1_67_, viewhelpin39_.viewhelpinghandpostID as viewhelp1_45_38_, viewhelpin39_.date_time as date2_45_38_, viewhelpin39_.studentID as studentID45_38_, viewhelpin39_.helpinghandID as helpingh4_45_38_, commenthel40_.helpinghandID as helpingh5_46_68_, commenthel40_.CommenthelpinghandpostID as Commenth1_68_, commenthel40_.CommenthelpinghandpostID as Commenth1_47_39_, commenthel40_.date_time as date2_47_39_, commenthel40_.comment as comment47_39_, commenthel40_.studentID as studentID47_39_, commenthel40_.helpinghandID as helpingh5_47_39_, viewhelpin41_.studentID as studentID7_69_, viewhelpin41_.viewhelpinghandpostID as viewhelp1_69_, viewhelpin41_.viewhelpinghandpostID as viewhelp1_45_40_, viewhelpin41_.date_time as date2_45_40_, viewhelpin41_.studentID as studentID45_40_, viewhelpin41_.helpinghandID as helpingh4_45_40_, commenthel42_.studentID as studentID7_70_, commenthel42_.CommenthelpinghandpostID as Commenth1_70_, commenthel42_.CommenthelpinghandpostID as Commenth1_47_41_, commenthel42_.date_time as date2_47_41_, commenthel42_.comment as comment47_41_, commenthel42_.studentID as studentID47_41_, commenthel42_.helpinghandID as helpingh5_47_41_ from student studentbea0_ inner join college collegebea1_ on studentbea0_.collegeID=collegebea1_.collegeid left outer join college_course college_co2_ on collegebea1_.collegeid=college_co2_.collegeID left outer join test testbean3_ on collegebea1_.collegeid=testbean3_.collegeID left outer join collegeactivitylog collegeact4_ on collegebea1_.collegeid=collegeact4_.collegeID left outer join assignment assignment5_ on collegebea1_.collegeid=assignment5_.collegeID inner join course coursebean6_ on studentbea0_.courseID=coursebean6_.courseid left outer join subject subjectbea7_ on coursebean6_.courseid=subjectbea7_.courseID left outer join faculty_subject faculty_su8_ on coursebean6_.courseid=faculty_su8_.courseID left outer join college_course college_co9_ on coursebean6_.courseid=college_co9_.courseID left outer join Job_Course jobcourseb10_ on coursebean6_.courseid=jobcourseb10_.courseID left outer join studentactivitylog studentact11_ on studentbea0_.studentID=studentact11_.studentID left outer join Job_View jobviewbea12_ on studentbea0_.studentID=jobviewbea12_.studentID left outer join job jobbean13_ on jobviewbea12_.jobID=jobbean13_.jobid left outer join applyjob applyjobbe14_ on studentbea0_.studentID=applyjobbe14_.studentID left outer join job jobbean15_ on applyjobbe14_.jobID=jobbean15_.jobid left outer join like_video likevideob16_ on studentbea0_.studentID=likevideob16_.studentID left outer join video videobean17_ on likevideob16_.videoID=videobean17_.videoid left outer join comment_video commentvid18_ on studentbea0_.studentID=commentvid18_.studentID left outer join video videobean19_ on commentvid18_.videoID=videobean19_.videoid left outer join like_quote likequoteb20_ on studentbea0_.studentID=likequoteb20_.studentID left outer join quote quotebean21_ on likequoteb20_.quoteid=quotebean21_.quoteid left outer join comment_quote commentquo22_ on studentbea0_.studentID=commentquo22_.studentID left outer join quote quotebean23_ on commentquo22_.quoteid=quotebean23_.quoteid left outer join like_articles likearticl24_ on studentbea0_.studentID=likearticl24_.studentID left outer join articles articlesbe25_ on likearticl24_.articlesid=articlesbe25_.articlesid left outer join comment_articles commentart26_ on studentbea0_.studentID=commentart26_.studentID left outer join articles articlesbe27_ on commentart26_.articlesID=articlesbe27_.articlesid left outer join like_lifeclubvideo likelifecl28_ on studentbea0_.studentID=likelifecl28_.studentID left outer join lifeclubvideo lifeclubvi29_ on likelifecl28_.videoid=lifeclubvi29_.videoid left outer join comment_lifeclubvideo commentlif30_ on studentbea0_.studentID=commentlif30_.studentID left outer join lifeclubvideo lifeclubvi31_ on commentlif30_.videoid=lifeclubvi31_.videoid left outer join like_ebook likeebookb32_ on studentbea0_.studentID=likeebookb32_.studentID left outer join ebook ebookbean33_ on likeebookb32_.ebookID=ebookbean33_.ebookid left outer join comment_ebook commentebo34_ on studentbea0_.studentID=commentebo34_.studentID left outer join ebook ebookbean35_ on commentebo34_.ebookID=ebookbean35_.ebookid left outer join submitassignment submitassi36_ on studentbea0_.studentID=submitassi36_.studentID left outer join assignment assignment37_ on submitassi36_.assignmentID=assignment37_.assignmentID left outer join helpinghand helpinghan38_ on studentbea0_.studentID=helpinghan38_.studentID left outer join ViewHelpingHandPostBean viewhelpin39_ on helpinghan38_.helpinghandID=viewhelpin39_.helpinghandID left outer join CommentHelpingHandPostBean commenthel40_ on helpinghan38_.helpinghandID=commenthel40_.helpinghandID left outer join ViewHelpingHandPostBean viewhelpin41_ on studentbea0_.studentID=viewhelpin41_.studentID left outer join CommentHelpingHandPostBean commenthel42_ on studentbea0_.studentID=commenthel42_.studentID where studentbea0_.studentID=?
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-9" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1361)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:2333)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2040)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1443)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1777)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1403)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1005)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
    at com.dao.StudentService.updateEducationStudentProfile(StudentService.java:469)
    at com.controller.Student.UpdateStudentProfileServlet.service(UpdateStudentProfileServlet.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
```

is it because of studentbean has many fields?

sometimes they give error "containerbackgroundprocessor".

This is happen only while i am updating studentprofile..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your JVM heap settings now ? 
How much data do you load from the DB?

Try
-Xms 512m -Xmx 1028m -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: i dont want to change size of any type of memory...i want to know why this happening.

Comment: Post your update code. Something might gone on infinite loop or your are loading very large millions of data. ??

Comment: yes...objstudentservice.update(studentbean) fires select query..and that query is problem cause it brings lots of data...see query in error stack in question.

Comment: Lots of data means, how much ? Try to unit test that select query alone separately and see if you get this same problem ?

Comment: studentbean contains 50 fields..and total 8 other beans are associates with student bean..

Comment: it selects all the fields from beans associates with student bean.

Comment: If there are too many data for children try to enable Lazy loading.